# Android 3.x. How to preserve text selection when opening a dialog

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-3.1-honeycomb

When dialog is shown, the word I selected by *double click* is losing selection.

Step-by-step:

1. I double click on a word, the word is selected and "Text Selection" menu is shown at the top of the sreen.
2. I click on a button and display a dialog. Once dialog is shown, the selection is cleared.

Notice, if I select text using keyboard in such way that "Text Selection" is NOT shown, then text selection is preserved. Also, selection is preserved on 2.2. The issue is only on 3.x when word selected by double click.

How can I fix this?